# gatsby does not fetch all media items from wordpress CMS

Tags: wordpress, image, graphql, gatsby

I am using `gatsby` with `wordpress` as a headless CMS to grab all `media` images and display them on a gatsby page . However out of the 3 images I have uploaded on wordpress only two are fetched to `gatsby` using `graphql` .

My graphql query inside a react component:

```
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query MediaQuery {
    
      allWpMediaItem {
        nodes {
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
              id
              gatsbyImageData(
                height: 700, 
                width: 900 ,
                placeholder: BLURRED , 
                quality:100,
                formats:AUTO,
                transformOptions: {fit:COVER}
              )
            }
          }
        }
      }

    }
  `);
```

I tried deleting the `cache` folder in gatsby and restarting with `gatsby develop` but the result is the same .

My images are unattached on wordpress and I do not think this is the problem as I have toggled the feature and still get the second and third image .

[image]

I would appreciate your help .

Comment: Which one is the unfetched?

Comment: @FerranBuireu the first

Comment: Just to check... have you tried renaming the image (removing the hyphens, like the second or the third are)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi it's over a year now but I encountered the same problem when building my Gatsby site, after googling and digging the docs, I found the solution that works for my case, it's stupidly simple! >_<

The [official doc](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/features/media-item-processing.md) says that **ONLY REFERENCED media items are sourced, and currently there is no way to pull all Media Items**. That's all.....Should've read the doc more carefully, literally wasted hours on solving this.

So I published a new post including the missing image, my running `npm run dev` console says it's pulling changes, and now running the GraphQL query again the image shows up.

---

edit:

sometimes updating existing post does not trigger gatsby-source-wordpress update, rerun `npm run dev` helps.